# Define a specific host for the API

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I'm trying to define a specific host to the API. It's possible to define it for each actions.

```
#[ApiResource(
collectionOperations: [
    'get' => [
        "host" => "api.project.com",
        'normalization_context' =>   ['groups' => ['read:events']]
    ]
],
itemOperations: [
    'get' => [
        "host" => "api.project.com",
        'normalization_context' =>   ['groups' => ['read:event']]
    ]
])
```

But is it possible to define it globally ? (in a configuration file for example)

Thanks

Comment: Just modify `config/routes/api_platform.yaml` and add a `host: api.project.com` entry.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think of the routing file